# No Data for IOPS while Selecting Storage Size 250GB or 500GB in Performance Storage

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am trying to place order in performance storage then API is returning null for `IOPS` when `250/500GB` is selected. Please make a needful favour. API that I am using to get the `IOPS` is given below:

```
https://[username]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Product_Package/222/getItemPrices?objectFilter={"itemPrices": { "attributes": { "value": { "operation": 250 } },  "categories": { "categoryCode": {    "operation": "performance_storage_iops" } },    "locationGroupId": {    "operation": "is null" } } }
```

Please make a needful favour.

Comment: The problem is not reproducible using a Test Account. Please I suggest you to open a SL ticket in order to isolate the problem. Some steps and some relevant code can help. But I recommend you don't provide `sensitive information` in this public Forum (e.g. ids, username, etc).

Comment: yeah sure mcruz I will not share sensitive information..

Comment: It would good idea to share your request, the issue may be due to the filters you are using

Comment: @NelsonRaulCaberoMendoza I am using below request :-
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Product_Package/222/getItemPrices?objectFilter={"itemPrices": { "attributes": { "value": { "operation": 250 } },  "categories": { "categoryCode": {    "operation": "performance_storage_iops" } },    "locationGroupId": {    "operation": "is null" } } }   but status for 250 Gb is successful but no data is there

Comment: { "attributes": { "value": { "operation": 250 } that is the issue, it does not exist that value. If you are looking for getting the IOPS=250 you need to filter that value in the description of the item or in its capacity.

Comment: @NelsonRaulCaberoMendoza please share an example of that..

Comment: use this object filter objectFilter={"itemPrices": { "item":{"capacity": {"operation" :2500}} ,"categories": { "categoryCode": { "operation": "performance_storage_iops" } }, "locationGroupId": { "operation": "is null" } } }

Comment: In another hand if you are looking for getting all the valid IOPS for the storage space 250 and 500, you have to use the following filter objectFilter={"itemPrices": { "attributes": { "value": { "operation": 1000 } }, "categories": { "categoryCode": { "operation": "performance_storage_iops" } }, "locationGroupId": { "operation": "is null" } } }, The result will return all the IOPS which work with storage spaces <= 1000 gbs. In case you need the IOPS which work for a storage space such as 1500, you have to change the value "1000" by "2000". I hope that I got the message acrooss.

Comment: @NelsonRaulCaberoMendoza If I uses IOPS ids corresponding to 100 GB storage space in place of 250 GB storage space, will it be compatible? As IOPS range for 100 GB and 250 GB storage space is 100 to 6000 IOPS i.e same. Now I need to know will ids for 100GB storage space and for 250 GB storage space will be same..?

Comment: yes all the IOPS are compatible for 250GBs of storage spaces. try calling the verify order it should work

Comment: @NelsonRaulCaberoMendoza I again got confusion. I need to have valid list of IOPS with IDs corresponding to selected storage. for e.g. If I select 250 gb storage then I need to get the valid list of IOPS(ranging between 100-6000 IOPS) with there ids and If I select 80 GB storage then I should get only IOPS which are ranging (100 - 4000 IOPS with ids). But using above calls its not clear to me. Please assist.

Comment: The list is valid for 250GBs, the attributes section contains the retrictions for the item in this case this restriction is for storage space, now for some storage spaces such as 80 or 20 the resctriction is specific for that value so that´s why you request works fine, in the case for 250gb or 500gb the restriction is a "range of values" if you take a look at the attributes you will see that it contains two values "CAPACITY_RESTRICTION_MIN" and "CAPACITY_RESTRICTION_MAX" that is the range which is 100 and 1000, that means that the values work for all storage spaces between those values.

Comment: for the values such as 80 or 20, the CAPACITY_RESTRICTION_MIN and CAPACITY_RESTRICTION_MAX are the same value. Now do you undestand?

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to get data for IOPS selecting storage size 250GB or 500GB in Performance Storage (Block Storage / File Storage).

Could you describe more about this issue? code that you are trying or the steps that you followed?

Answer (score 0):

you have to use the following filter objectFilter={"itemPrices": { "attributes": { "value": { "operation": 1000 } }, "categories": { "categoryCode": { "operation": "performance_storage_iops" } }, "locationGroupId": { "operation": "is null" } } }, The result will return all the IOPS which work with storage spaces <= 1000 gbs. In case you need the IOPS which work for a storage space such as 1500, you have to change the value "1000" by "2000". I hope that I got the message acrooss

Regards

Comment: in the help you provided we will get all the values less than 1000 GB. but in the case of 250 gb storage space iops values are always <= 250. Here we will get values in the range of 250-1000 also. Which are redundant for 250 gb storage space. These should not be be available there. How can a user prevent filter only values which are in 0-250 range..?

Comment: Wait waht rebundant data are you talking about?

Comment: I reviewed the result and all data are valid I do not see rebundand data. You can order 250 GBs storage capacity, with IOPS from 100 to 6000,which means you should have 60 available IOPS and that is what I got with the filter. SO what rebundand data are you talking about explain.

Answer (score 0):

I am given

```
 objectFilter = {"itemPrices": { "attributes": { "value": { "operation": 250 } }, 
"categories": { "categoryCode": { "operation": "performance_storage_iops" } },
 "locationGroupId": { "operation": "is null" } } }
```

but `IOPS` getting null. please check below attached.

[image: Response for storage size 250GB]

Comment: Can you please update me on my query. I am waiting for your answer

Comment: Can you please update me on my query. My work is pending because of this issue. Can you please solve my issue and update me as soon as possible