# Querying osFormatType for Block Storage

Tags: ruby, rest, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I know I can use the following to order Performance storage, but what API endpoint (and object masks) can I use to query a list of osFormatTypes?

```
{
  "parameters": [
    {
      "packageId": 222,
      "location": 154820,
      "osFormatType": {
        "id": 12,
        "keyName": "LINUX"
      },
      "complexType": "SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Network_PerformanceStorage_Iscsi",
      "prices": [
        {
          "id": 40672   # Block Storage (Performance)
        },
        {
          "id": 40682   # 20 GB Storage Space
        },
        {
          "id": 40792   # 100 IOPS
        }
      ],
      "quantity": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand what was so perplexing. I was asking how to query the SoftLayer (hence the SoftLayer tag) osFormatType and Ruber Cuellar knew exactly what I was asking and answered it perfectly. Thanks, Ruber!

Comment: Yeah, the question is clear, I agree with Jonathan Levine, anytime!

Comment: @RuberCuellar Although I would have liked to see more context in the question, a subject matter expert did find it perfectly clear and unambiguous, so I'll admit I erred and vote to reopen it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following Rest request:

```
https://$user:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Network_Storage_Iscsi_OS_Type/getAllObjects

Method: Get
```

**References:**

- [SoftLayer_Network_Storage_Iscsi_OS_Type::getAllObjects](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Storage_Iscsi_OS_Type/getAllObjects)

Comment: I have a follow up question. How can I determine the maximum IOPS of a storage space? The portal lists the minimum and maximum IOPS but I can't for the life of me find it in the API.

Thanks!

Comment: This is something complex to understand, but take a look the following forum: [Performance storage We are selecting Storage size 250/500GB but no data in IOPS through REST API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36734566/performance-storage-we-are-selecting-storage-size-250-500gb-but-no-data-in-iops/36752383#36752383), let me know any doubt or comment that you have about it

Comment: Worked like a charm in ruby! Thanks again!